# Create/Download an Image using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

Sorry to ask this issue as it puzzled me for a long time using Codeigniter.
Here is what I am doing. 
As seen below, I am displaying a form where there is a button "Download".
This download button should download that image into PDF file where the details 
are written on it (those in RED box). 
[image]

So this is the process I am doing.

1. Create an Image on the fly (dynamic) using PHP function **imagecreatefromjpeg**.
2. Download/Copy that image generated in the URL and save it in a folder in the server
3. Generate a PDF using mpdf referencing to that image created dynamically.

I can now create an image dynamically like this one below. Where I can write a text into the image (*see 2015 text written in the image*)
[image]

My problem is, when I click the "Download" button, it should not display
the image in the browser but automatically download it in the folder on the server then it calls the function MPDF to convert it into PDF file. Is this possible?

**Code:**

This is the Method called when user clicked the "Download" button

```
public function download_pdf() {
    $data['image']  = $this -> get_photo();
    $this -> mpdf_convert_pdf();        
}
```

This is the function that creates the image dynamically. Once created, it should download it in the specified folder location on the server.

```
function get_photo(){       
    //Create an Image on the Fly
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    $imgpath = site_url() . 'assets/images/2316.jpg';
    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);      
    $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    $font_path = 'assets/fonts/arial.ttf';
    $text = "2015!";
    imagettftext($img, 100, 0, 300, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);

    //Copy an Image from URL into a server folder
    $content = file_get_contents('http://localhost/run_ms/ccertificates/get_photo');
    file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\run_ms\assets\images\thumb\Test.png', $content);
}
```

And here's is the part where it converts the image into PDF file.

```
public function mpdf_convert_pdf() {
    include ('application/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'Legal', '', '', 5, 5, 5, '5', '5', '0');     

    //Display output
    $html = '<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\run_ms\assets\images\thumb\Test.png">';

    //display PDF file
    $mpdf -> WriteHTML($html);

    $mpdf -> Output('Converted_pdf', 'D');
    exit ;
}
```

Thank you so much experts any inputs you may share into this query of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to display the created image in the browser, you need to specify the path where it will be saved into your server. Since my issue before is how to download the created image and not to be displayed in the browser.

To do so, you need to specify the path on the fm **imagejpeg**

So instead of doing like this:

```
imagejpeg($img);
```

It should be done this way:

```
imagejpeg($img,'C:\xampp\htdocs\rn_ms\assets\images\thumb\test.png');
```

The second parameter is the path and filename where it will be saved in the server as stated in the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php ). So, if the path was not specified, it will be shown in the browser but if specified, then it will be downloaded as file in the specified server path.

Hopes this will help to other developers. :)

Comment: I use `FCPATH` and `imagejpeg($img, FCPATH . 'assets/images/thumb/test.png');`

Answer (score 0):

so the point is, in every "Download" button you clicked, the pdf should open to new tab and showing the data first?

Comment: Hi Elos,  thanks a lot for your reply. But I have now solved it. I will share to everyone the solution...

Comment: when answering don' t ask more questions, try giving an answer to the question

Comment: Hi Davejal, I posted here because I dont know the answer before. Thats why I ASKED and did not ANSWERED. But when elos replied to my question, I told him that I have already solved which I will share to everyone.